# Use null object as argument to method

Tags: c++, methods, null

Consider the following piece of code

```
class Foo
    {
    public:
    //...
        bool valueFirstGet(int& value) const
            {
            if(this==nullptr)
                {return 0;}
            value=values[0];
            return 1;
            }
    //...

    private:
        int* values;
        size_t n_values;
    };

int main()
    {
    Foo* obj=findObject("key");
    int value;
    if(!obj->valueFirstGet(value))
        {printf("key does not exist\n");}

    return 0;
    }
```

findObject returns nullptr if it cannot find the object. Is it ok to let the member function do the null check instead of its caller. In my code, there are several calls to findObject directly followed by a call to valueFirstGet so leaving the check to the caller makes the code ugly.

EDIT:

Is there a cleaner way to avoid all null checking besides having findObject to throw an exception instead of returning null?

EDIT 2:

What about a static wrapper?

Comment: calling `valueFirstGet` on a null pointer is undefined behavior

Comment: @ratchetfreak It works in g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1~ubuntu12.04.1~ppa1) 4.7.2 with -O3 so gcc does not skip the if statement. It would be undefined behavior to try to access values and n_values, which it does not.

Comment: just because it works on some compilers doesn't mean it's not undefined behavior, and the optimizer can still reorder field accesses to before the null test

Comment: Remember that "works as expected" is a valid result from undefined behavior (as is "brick the machine")

Comment: The sane solution *is* to throw an exception on failure. Nulls are one of the biggest mistakes modern languages continue to perpetuate, and they're only just starting to realize this. If you can't use exceptions for performance or standards reasons, consider either a `hasObject(String): bool` method or a `tryFindObject(String, out Foo*): bool`. Null pointers are an error condition, not a valid return result.

Comment: @Phoshi In my situation, a missing key does not necessary imply a failure. Therefore, findObject should not throw.

Comment: @user877329: Then ignore that bit and take the rest of the post. Null pointers are still an error condition, and without a `Maybe` or `Option` type I think your best bet is something like `tryFindObject` or `hasObject`. Nulls are harmful, avoid if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The null-check in `valueFirstGet` can not yield true without there being undefined behavior in the program, because you must dereference a null-pointer (which causes UB) to let that test yield true. The nasty thing about undefined behavior is that *any* behavior is fully sanctioned and that behavior might change between compiler versions or even optimization levels without notice.

The correct way to go about this is to have the check in the caller or in a helper method. If the `findObject`/`valueFirstGet` calls are commonly paired with no further use for the object returned by `findObject`, you can even do something like this:

```
bool tryValueFirstGet(const std::string& key, int& value)
{
    Foo* obj=findObject(key);
    return obj && obj->valueFirstGet(value);
}
```

The short-circuit behaviour of `&&` ensures that `valueFirstGet` will only be called if the object could be found.

Comment: Also this gives a gain in performance, since, in some cases i would know that I do not have a null pointer, and then the check is unnecessary. Using a helper method, gives the programmer the choice of guarded/unguarded behaviour.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you absolutely want to guarantee that you can call valueFirstGet without problems, then return a wrapper object which is never null and has a method valFirstGet which performs this check internally.  However, if that is strictly the only reason for making a wrapper class, it's a waste of time and energy.

Answer (score 3):

A common and useful way to avoid null pointer checking is by using the [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).  Essentially, instead of using the language's built-in definition of a null object as "a null pointer you can't dereference," you create your own definition with useful null behavior appropriate to your situation.  Remember, you're a programmer.  You don't have to settle for whatever limited facilities are built into the language.

Using the null object pattern for your example might look something like this:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    int getCount() {
      return n_values;
    }

    int firstValue() {
      return values[0];
    }
}

class NullFoo : public Foo {
  public:
    int getCount() {
      return 0;
    }

    int firstValue() {
      return 0; // Return a useful default if you want, or throw an exception if you want.
    }
}
```

Then if your `findObject` doesn't find the key, it instantiates and returns a `NullFoo` (or returns a reference to a static object), which can be dereferenced without undefined behavior, and can provide any kind of default behavior you like, including throwing an exception if the situation calls for it.

The nice thing is your regular `Foo` can be *guaranteed* to have at least one element, so you can skip a lot of checks there as well.  All the checks are done at instantiation time, and polymorphism handles the rest.

Comment: This is a good technique in fully polymorphic language like Java, but in C++ polymorphism is often not the preferred approach. E.g. the virtuals are more likely _slower_ than the null pointer check.

Comment: you misunderstood the question, and gave a wrong answer. In c++, `this` can never be nullptr.

Comment: while it is true that in C++ we often have better options than late -bound polymorphism, that does not invalidate this answer. The Null Object Pattern is very useful in C++, too.

Comment: @JanHudec, in a tight loop you might have a point.  However, in modern computer architectures, vtable lookups are common and highly optimized.  We're not going for raw speed here.  We're going for the clearest code with the least possibility of accidentally missing a null check where one is needed.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt: Of course. But cleanest code in C++ does _not have `virtual` all over the place_.

Comment: @BЈовић, you misunderstood my answer.  Using the null object pattern, `this` won't ever be a nullptr.  It's a pointer to a valid object with default behavior you specify.

Comment: null object pattern is something else. `this` can never be nullptr, unless is set by a really bad programmer. btw changing `this` to point to something else is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Summary:

The design problem you've presented actually deals with two kinds of issues, thus it involves two classes of possible solutions too.

> Is it ok to let the member function do the null check instead of its
>   caller?

Semantically speaking, it does not make sense. To call an instance method of a null object is logically incorrect because the object does not exist yet.

So that being said, a cleaner solution to this design problem would be to handle the case as clearly as possible by using the exception mechanism available in the language. Let the findObject throw the exception and let the caller routine handles it as needed. This results to a more readable code.

> In my code, there are several calls to findObject directly followed
>   by a call to valueFirstGet so leaving the check to the caller makes
>   the code ugly.

This is where a wrapper method will come in handy to avoid repeating yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, working with large chunks of legacy code, such **null** checking proves to be helpful. But I will never recommend it for a class being written from scratch.

Also note, that in `valueFirstGet()` the **&value** could also be **null**. I have worked with legacy code, where such situations had to be taken care of, too.

Comment: why and how are such checks helpful?

Comment: @BЈовић: because the C++ libraries I was porting from Win32 to Android NDK could not support exceptions, and they were almost cross-platform, only some objects were Windows-only, and happened to be NULL in Android. Few couples of added lines let us run the huge codebase without major rewrite.

Comment: as Bart wrote in his answer, this can never be nullptr, therefore the check makes no sense at all

Comment: Bart only wrote that before the null is sensed, you hit an "undefined behaviour". So far, so good. When you know exactly your target and your toolchain, you can know how they behave in this situation. Specifically, for Android NDK with gcc, a non-virtual method happily arrives to `this != 0` clause. And believe me, there were tons of other undefined behaviours the library depended upon.